# Is there any physical interpretation for $\nabla\cdot(\nabla \times F)=0$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, vector-fields

It is well known that the divergence of the curl is always 0. Mathematically I understand why this happens ($d^2=0$ where $d$ is the exterior derivative) but today I was wondering what is the physical meaning of this.

The divergence represents the volume density of the outward flux of a vector field from an infinitesimal volume around a given point (from Wikipedia) and the curl describes the infinitesimal rotation of a 3-dimensional vector field (also from Wikipedia).

Does this mean that the rotation of a vector field is always stable and doesn't go inwards or outwards? What is the physical meaning of the divergence of the curl equals 0?

Comment: Given that it is true for *any* vector field I don't think there is any physical significance.

Comment: You can check Feynman's Lectures on [curl free & divergence free fields](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_03.html#Ch3-S7); there he presents a nice example as why this relation is true.

Comment: Not sure I'd use "stable" here, but seems to me that ${\rm div}({\rm curl}(\mathbf F))$ signifies that the flux through any infinitesimal volume of a field that is rotating is zero. Perhaps it could be better to say that it means that there are no sources or sinks with a field that is rotating?

Comment: @KyleKanos: But you're not taking the divergence of a rotating field, you're taking the divergence of its curl, which may or may not rotate.

Comment: @Javier: Well if $\mathbf F$ is not rotating, then $\nabla\times\mathbf F=\mathbf 0$ and ${\rm anything}\cdot\mathbf 0=0$ identically & it's not terribly interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any physical meaning. There is geometric meaning, however, which is almost as good, in this case.

Consider the integral theorems, namely the Kelvin-Stokes-theorem: $$ \int_\Sigma \nabla\times \mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\int_{\partial\Sigma}\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{l}, $$ and the Gauss-theorem: $$ \int_U \nabla\cdot\mathbf{V}\ d^3x=\int_{\partial U}\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{A},$$ where $\Sigma$ is some smooth surface, $U$ is a 3-dimensional domain of integration, and $\partial$ is the boundary operator, eg. the one that maps a set to its boundary.

Now let $U$ be once again a volume, and let $\mathbf{V}$ be a **completely arbitrary** vector field, and apply these theorems twice in succession: $$ \int_{\partial\partial U}\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=\int_{\partial U}\nabla\times\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{A}=\int_U\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{V})\ d^3x=0. $$ These integrals are all zero, because $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{V})$ is zero for any $\mathbf{V}$, however, if you look at the first expression, $$ \int_{\partial\partial U}\mathbf{V}\cdot d\mathbf{l}=0 $$, this must be true for **all** vector fields $\mathbf{V}$. The only way it is true for all such vector fields is that if the domain of integration $\partial\partial U$ is a set of zero measure.

Therefore, the identity $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf{V})=0$ essentially says that for a three-dimensional volume $U$, *the boundary of its boundary is always zero*. If you think about it, this is pretty obvious, but this line of thought actually *proves* this.

This is even more elegant for differential forms, where you can repeat the same procedure by applying the generalized stokes theorem twice, and you will essentially get that $\mathrm{dd}=0$ corresponds to $\partial\partial=0$.

Comment: The discussion of $d^2 = 0$ and that the boundaries of a boundary is empty in MTW is very good and has great illustrations.

Answer (score 0):

First I should say that it is a mathematical definition and does not carry any physical meaning necessarily. But as an example it relates the Maxwell equations:
$$\nabla\times E=-\frac{\partial B}{\partial t}$$
and
$$\nabla \cdot B=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow \nabla\cdot(\nabla\times E)=-\frac{\partial \nabla\cdot B}{\partial t}=0$$

and the continuity equation can be deduced from
$$\nabla\times H=J+\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}$$
and
$$\nabla \cdot D=\rho$$$$\Longrightarrow \nabla\cdot(\nabla\times H)=\nabla\cdot J+\frac{\partial \nabla\cdot D}{\partial t}=0$$
which is the continuity equation:
$$\nabla\cdot J=-\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}$$

If one day in future a magnetic monopole is discovered in reality, as some people are interested in it for some reasons, then $\nabla \cdot B$ is not zero anymore, but, mathematically $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times E)$ has to be zero.

This means that a new entity has to be defined instead of $B$ in order to hold the $\nabla\cdot(\nabla\times E)=0$. This is how math can help physics.

Comment: Although correct, I don't think the above addresses the question because the left hand sides always vanish; as such, we demand the rhs to vanish as well (namely those are the *equation of motion* for the fields and the current, as you pointed out). The question, though, is about the meaning of the lhs vanishing for the field that occurs in it (the $\textbf{E}$ field, in your example), rather than its consequences on the possible rhs of an equation of motion.

Comment: You are right. Anyway I don't think that divergence of curl has any physical meaning as long as we attribute something to it.

Comment: May be we can look into conditions where $\nabla\cdot(\nabla \times F)=0$ fails, (when $F$ is not differentiable?)

Comment: I agree with the fact that there ought not necessarily be any particular physical meaning in $d^2=0$, especially because it is always true *by definition*. Regarding the point of $\textbf{F}$ not being differentiable: interesting, although all the calculus on manifolds (and hence Stoke's theorems and hence all the rest) are *defined* based on the differentiability assumption.

Answer (score 0):

It quite simply means that the radial direction is orthogonal to the tangential direction.

The universe in which we live behaves, as far as we can tell and measure, as a 3D volume (time aside for now:). A 3D volume is defined by 3 orthogonal directions. We can choose to look at a 2D cross-section of this volume, and we get a 2D plain, in which, every point is defined by 2 orthogonal direction. One can show these directions can be X\Y, but also R\Teata. R is the radial direction, and Theata is the tangential direction.

Because these directions are orthogonal, BY DEFINITION, it's not hard to understand that if you measure the radial component of a purely tangential scale (the deliverance of the curl), of the other way around, you get nothing - because radialiry is not tangential, and tangentiality is not radial :)

Comment: Could you expand on why you think this is the case?

Comment: Expansion has occurred.

Comment: I don't see how this is related to $\textrm{div}(\textrm{curl}\,\textbf{v})=0$.

Comment: Because, as written, the divergence (which is a measure of radial component of a 2D vector) of the curl (which is a measure of the tangential component of a 2D vector) is by definition 0, because they are orthogonal.